# Is Visual WebGui like an X-Server written in JavaScript?

Tags: .net, x11, visual-web-gui

I am trying to understand [Visual WebGui](http://www.visualwebgui.com/), am I right to think of it as being like a X-Server (X-Windows) but with the UI server written in JavaScript?

Are there any other products like it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question.
Actually there is a great resemblance between the two.

Visual WebGui provides an abstraction layer to the server-side object model by the framework's client-side core (uploaded on first loading) on the browser.

With Visual WebGui you are able to develop applications on server-side Microsoft .NET code and have them render to the client's browsers over HTTP or HTTPS using HTML, JavaScript and CSS (no client plug-in required).
That is all without having to ever write or even see a line of HTML, JavaScript or CSS code.
Visual WebGui also provides superior security on the client, especially as the client only holds the UI that it displays and has no control or access over data located on the server.
Visual WebGui also provides you out-of-the-box compatibility for the major browsers: Mozilla Firefox, MS Internet Explorer, Google Chrome and Apple Safari (including mobile device versions).
We are launching these days a new version of our framework that adds full support for Google Android browsers.

*Products like Visual WebGui*

We are familiar with several frameworks and libraries that provide a partial or isolated solution for either client controls that use JavaScript or some intermediate technology.
We have never been introduced to a technology that provides a solution for web client-server application development, that is as complete as Visual WebGui.

For a technological overview of the Visual WebGui framework, please view this article [here](http://visualwebgui.com/Technology/tabid/619/Default.aspx).

Please download the SDK from this page [here](http://mailto%3aSupport@visualwebgui.com/tabid/110/default.aspx) and experiment. You have a 30 day trial and a free Express version you can work with.

I will be more than happy to answer your questions. You can write to us on Support@VisualWebGui.com.

Regards,

---

Ori Cohen

Support Manager, the Visual WebGui team